# Polarization vectors

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, vectors, polarization, plane-wave

There is the known relation between circular and linear polarization bases:

$e_x = \{ 1,0,0\}$, $e_y = \{0,1,0\}$, $e_z = \{0,0,1\}$ and $e_{\pm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_x \pm ie_y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \{ 1,\pm i, 0\}$, $e_z = \{0,0,1\}$.

However, there is also this representation

$e_x = \{\cos \theta \cos \phi, \cos \theta \sin \phi, -\sin \theta\}$, $e_y = \{ -\sin \phi, \cos \phi, 0 \}$ and $e_z = \{0,0,1\}$.

To start with, if I take $\cos \theta$ for the arbitrary vector, I just end up projecting it on $z$ which makes all the projections $\sin \phi$ and $\cos\phi$ meaningless.

Where do these come from? Is there a derivation of these? I failed to find an explanation. I can see the rotation around z by angle $\phi$, but what are those $\cos$ and $\sin$ of $\theta$ in $x$ and why don't they show up in $y$ or $z$ then?

Comment: "To start with, if I take cosθ  for the arbitrary vector" - I don't quite follow what you mean. The $\cos\theta$ is multipled by $\cos\phi$ and similar, so it's the projection onto the plane normal to $z$, followed by the projection onto the bases of this plane. Is this what you mean? Also, be aware of differences in definitions of latitudes / colatitudes (zeniths).

Comment: Rotate the vector $(0,\,0,\,1)$ through $\pi/2-\theta$ radians about the $y$ axis. Then rotate the result $\phi$ radians about the $z$ axis, and see what you get.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance the projection on $xy$-plane is $\sin \theta$, not $\cos$, assuming the conventional choice of the spherical directional angles.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance with the rotation around $y$ axis by the angle $\theta$ $e_z$ requires an angle in $z$ component, which is not there.

Answer (score -1):

The electric field only have two internal degrees of freedom. These are represented by the states of polarization. Any state of polarization can therefore be expressed as a superposition of *two* basis states. (Not *three* as you seem to indicate.) One can for instance use the linear $x$- and $y$-polarization states as the basis states to express any other polarization state. By doing this one restricts all these polarization states to the $x,y$-plane. By implication we then assume that the electric field is propagating in the $z$-direction, because the propagation direction (of a plane wave) is always perpendicular to the polarization vector.

What happens when one the wave propagates in some arbitrary direction? Then one needs to define a basis that lies in the plane that is perpendicular to that propagation vector (unit vector $\hat{k}$). One way to do this is to pick some arbitrary vector $\hat{n}$ (not parallel to $\hat{k}$); compute the cross product and normalize
$$ \hat{e}_1=\frac{\hat{n}\times\hat{k}}{|\hat{n}\times\hat{k}|} . $$
This gives us one basis vector. The other one then readily follows from 
$$ \hat{e}_2=\hat{e}_1\times\hat{k} . $$
These two basis vector can now be used to express any state of polarization for the wave propagating in the direction of $\hat{k}$.

One can, alternatively, obtain a polarization basis in a different plane by performing the appropriate rotations on those defined in the $x,y$-plane.

*Addition*:

Based on the comment, it seems that the OP has some confusion with the situation in quantum electrodynamics (QED). Pity this was not mentioned in the question.

When one performs the calculation of Feynman diagram, one needs to retain all the degrees of freedom for the internal lines associated with the propagators, because these lines represent fields that could be *off-shell*. The internal degrees of freedom are in this case represented by four degrees of freedom, because the gauge field has four components.

However, for external lines the fields are always *on-shell*. Here, one would find that the [Ward identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity) (resulting from gauge invariance), together with the dispersion relation (which incorporates a zero mass that is also protected by the gauge invariance), reduces the degrees of freedom to just two. So, for any observable propagating optical field one finds only two internal degrees of freedom. Therefore, the state of polarization of light can be completely specified in terms of just two basis vector.

Comment: Whell, helicity basis is defined as $\{e_{\pm}, e_z\}$ in terms of $\{e_x, e_y, e_z\}$, which is not what I "seem to indicate", but what is in formal QED description of polarization states. I do not understand it, but I know it is there. Check any QED textbook and/or calculations of atomic transition amplitudes in Atomic Physics...

Comment: The Ward identities in QED reduce the number of internal degree of freedom to 2. So there can only be two basis vectors for polarization.

Comment: The origin of the approach you are talking about, due to my understanding, lyes in assuming plane-wave approximation (!) for all the excitations of the QED vacuum. I might be wrong though. But it is a philosophical question which I don't want to argue about here. See, for example, http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221b/photons.pdf.

Comment: Not sure I get your point. The plane wave basis is a complete orthogonal basis. Any other complete orthogonal basis would be related to it by unitary transformations. Hence, they would share the same properties. Philosophy has nothing to say about the matter. The notes you refer to also clearly show that the polarization vector is expressed in term of two basis vectors.

Comment: how to get eqn. 17 and 18 in those notes? That's what I am after. Thanks=)